# Class cast exceptions when retrieving a beans from CDI

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, jboss-weld

I'm running into a strange problem and error message that I do not understand.  I'm running my application on JBoss 7 EAP.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast ejbs.LoginManager$417755913$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$ to ejbs.LoginManager
```

I'm trying to programatically retrieve an EJB from the CDI context by using its interface and am getting this error message.  I've created a sample proof-of-concept that is trying to retrieve EJB beans from the CDI context

```
public <T> T getSesionBean(Class<T> clazz, String name) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    try {
        InitialContext initContext = new InitialContext();

        return clazz.cast(CDI.current().select(clazz).get());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

It is being called as:

```
LoginManager login = getSesionBean(LoginManager.class);
```

with my EJB defined as:

```
@Stateless(name="LoginManager")
@Local(LoginManager.class)
@LocalBinding(jndiBinding="LoginManager")
public class LoginManagerBean implements LoginManager {
...
...
...
}
```

I don't understand it.  I'm expecting the bean being retrieved from the context to be a proxy.  Shouldn't it be castable to my interface?  Otherwise, how am I supposed to retrieve it?

More interestingly, this does not seem to be a consistent error; sometimes the code works fine.  Sometimes it fails.  I haven't been able to determine what makes it work or throw an exception.

I found a related issue [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-1498), but not sure if this is the same problem and/or which version of Weld is used in JB7EAP.  I'm including the following dependency in my application:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
        <version>10.1.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Am I doing something completely wrong?  If this is a Weld bug, can I use a different proxy system than Weld?

Comment: Any particular reason you're using CDI as a service locator instead of just injecting the bean in the target object?

Comment: I'm in the process of migrating a legacy application that uses jndi lookup to retrieve the beans in static methods, etc.  Injecting the beans directly is a significant refactoring endeavor so my first step is to replace the jndi lookups by cdi lookups to prove the concept that it should work.  Next step well be to start refactoring their usage.

Comment: Ah.  Gotcha.  That explains the `InitialContext` as well.

Comment: @EricB. I think your problem is that the interface is annotated with `@Local`. If I remember correctly, changing it to a remote-interface would do the trick (but I am not sure since I don't know your complete setup)

Comment: @pphoenix. Thanks, but I want to use a Local interface which will differ from my remote one. At the moment, I'm just trying to get local interfaces working properly with DI.  And given that it is Local, I would have expected  CDI to work seamlessly.

Comment: For the record, JBEAP 7.0.x uses Weld 2.3.x. Anyhow, if you feel this could be a Weld bug, it would be nice if you could create a Weld issue _and attach a reproducer_. I am sure you could get more in-depth help there. By the looks of it, your EJB proxy (`LoginManager$417755913$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$`) looks like it had been proxied twice perhaps.

Comment: Everything you are doing is OK. The problem is in the annotation of the ejb bean. CDI will only consider a no interface ejb (local beans). Since your ejb implements an interface, CDI will not be able to use it as an injection candidate ,since the beans as defined by ejb for the interface and the bean implementation are themselves different, and hence CDI name mapping fails.

Comment: @Solaris thanks.  My problem is that the issue is intermittent.  Sometimes I can launch jboss and it works fine.  Sometimes I get the error.  Usually when launched via the eclipse plugin, but even that isn't consistent.  So im very perplexed how to recreate a sample to reproduce this consistently.  I'm happy to post my sample poc, but don't think it will help tremendously.

Comment: @maress Interesting.  I did not know that about CDI.  But how does that explain why it happens only intermittently? If that's the reason, I would expect it to fail consistently.  Additionally, I see the proxy listing it as a proxy to  the LoginManager class and not the LoginManagerBean.  I would expect it to show ur as a proxy to the Bean (impl) class - no?

Comment: Because of possibility of more than one bean, classloader issues may result to the wrong class being assigned to the CDI proxy

Comment: Indeed - I am including my ejb jar file in both the EAR and the WAR file, which causes a duplication of classes.  But according to the WF docs (https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly), the Local Resources (ie: classes within my WAR) would have a higher dependence than those from the EAR.  If that is the case, is my problem that I have the EJB implementation class in my WAR as well?  Must my war only have a copy of the LoginManager interface and not the impl code?  Wouldn't that be an issue that the EJB interface is in the ejbs.jar and in my war?